# Video Conferencing like video grid using css grid

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-grid

I am trying to create a video conferencing like grid. I am trying using css-grid but somehow I am not being able to accomplish what I am looking for. The idea is simple, have a grid of videos on screen and paginate the videos to next page which doesn't fit in the first.

I tried using the following:

```
<div className="videoContainer">
    <div className="videoWrapper">Cam 1</div>
    <div className="videoWrapper">Cam 2</div>
    <div className="videoWrapper">Cam 3</div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.videoContainer {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
.videoWrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

What I am looking for is some pointers/ hints/ any articles(didn't find anything useful) that point to the direction I want to go.

I have a simple layout as follows to explain (Left column for large screen devices, right column for mobile devices):

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. Let me know if you find any.

Answer (score 15):

I do not recommend using widths and heights with percentages. The important thing here is to respect the aspec ratio.

[image]

Example:

https://alicunde.github.io/Videoconference-Dish-CSS-JS/

Code:

https://github.com/Alicunde/Videoconference-Dish-CSS-JS

I have solved this problem today. First I started using CSS3 Grid, but the result did not respect the aspect ratio of the cameras.

Then I tried Flex, but it is not possible to cover defined surfaces. So I have created this pretty basic script.

The rest of the screens you need are easy to develop.

Phone version:

[image]

It is fast (resize event, load event):

[image]

Excuse my English.

Comment: Well, this looks good. Certainly moving in the right direction but, what if there are above 250 participants? The participants screen becomes way too small. May be it can be worked around by adding some kind of pagination and limiting the camera screens not go below a certain width?

Comment: Also, on mobile if there are 4 participants, currently they get stacked up but it would look great if it was to happen like the wireframe shown above.

Comment: Yes, but that does not require any complicated programming, it simply places each camera in absolute position. Surely in 1 week add that functionality. The only difficult thing here is to maintain the aspect ratio.

For that, add a click event to each camera and modify the css of that camera.

In case you want to have an exact scheme like yours, you should create different screens depending on the number of cameras. There is no CSS functionality that is smart about this. The script I have posted is to have 30 participants at the same time.

Comment: I recommend that you look at Agora Web SDK, they have an example that looks more like what you are looking for. They make use of Grid.

https://webdemo.agora.io/agora-web-showcase/ (many examples)

Comment: Now with animation (reload cache): https://alicunde.github.io/Videoconference-Dish-CSS-JS/

Comment: creating different screens depending on cameras would become a huge task, keeping in consideration about different screen sizes too. Need to figure out a way to make it easier.

Comment: @Salvatore, you're a genius, man! The only thing I would change in the repo is to rename the `increment` to the `potentialWidth`. Because it took me a while to grasp what we're trying to achieve in the `area` method